# Error 1064 en MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Cree las tablas con sus respectivas relaciones, luego cuando le doy a "Database" > "Forward Enginner" para verificar que el script que genere MySQL Workbench sea el  correcto, me sale este error..

**Error** que aparece al generar el **script**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y acá abajo comparto todo el **Script** que se genera, al parecer es error de sintaxis y que el problema viene de la tabla **"Equipo"**. Desconozco si los script generados en MySQL pueden tener errores.
Estuve averiguando mucho y no me tope con la solución, me había pasado antes (con otras tablas generadas) y lo resolví reinstalando **MySQL**; luego probé el script y no me dio ningún error.
No quiero tener que estar reinstalando cada vez que pruebe un script.

```
    -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema tech&tech
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema tech&tech
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `tech&tech` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`Cliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`Cliente` (
  `idCliente` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `telefono` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `tipoDocumento` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `numeroDocumento` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCliente`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`Localidad`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`Localidad` (
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cliente_idCliente` INT NOT NULL,
  `idLocalidad` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Cliente_idCliente`, `idLocalidad`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Localidad_Cliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Cliente_idCliente`)
    REFERENCES `tech&tech`.`Cliente` (`idCliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`Empresa`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`Empresa` (
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cliente_idCliente` INT NOT NULL,
  `idEmpresa` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Cliente_idCliente`, `idEmpresa`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Empresa_Cliente1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Cliente_idCliente`)
    REFERENCES `tech&tech`.`Cliente` (`idCliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`Equipo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`Equipo` (
  `numeroSerie` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `modelo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `añoFabricacion` DATE NOT NULL,
  `añoAlta` DATE NOT NULL,
  `idCliente` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numeroSerie`),
  INDEX `idCliente_idx` (`idCliente` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idCliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`)
    REFERENCES `tech&tech`.`Cliente` (`idCliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`OrdenTrabajo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`OrdenTrabajo` (
  `fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `rechazado` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cliente` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `numeroOrden` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCliente` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numeroOrden`),
  INDEX `idCliente_idx` (`idCliente` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idCliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`)
    REFERENCES `tech&tech`.`Cliente` (`idCliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`Detalle`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`Detalle` (
  `servicio` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `precio` INT NOT NULL,
  `idDetalle` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OrdenTrabajo_numeroOrden` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDetalle`, `OrdenTrabajo_numeroOrden`),
  INDEX `fk_Detalle_OrdenTrabajo1_idx` (`OrdenTrabajo_numeroOrden` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Detalle_OrdenTrabajo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OrdenTrabajo_numeroOrden`)
    REFERENCES `tech&tech`.`OrdenTrabajo` (`numeroOrden`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`Factura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`Factura` (
  `idFactura` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `numeroFactura` INT NOT NULL,
  `tipoFactura` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cliente` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `numeroOrden` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFactura`),
  INDEX `numeroOrden_idx` (`numeroOrden` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `numeroOrden`
    FOREIGN KEY (`numeroOrden`)
    REFERENCES `tech&tech`.`OrdenTrabajo` (`numeroOrden`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`DetalleFactura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`DetalleFactura` (
  `idDetalleFactura` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `detalle` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `Factura_idFactura` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDetalleFactura`, `Factura_idFactura`),
  INDEX `fk_DetalleFactura_Factura1_idx` (`Factura_idFactura` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_DetalleFactura_Factura1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Factura_idFactura`)
    REFERENCES `tech&tech`.`Factura` (`idFactura`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tech&tech`.`FormaPago`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech&tech`.`FormaPago` (
  `idFormaPago` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipoPago` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Factura_idFactura` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFormaPago`, `Factura_idFactura`),
  INDEX `fk_FormaPago_Factura1_idx` (`Factura_idFactura` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_FormaPago_Factura1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Factura_idFactura`)
    REFERENCES `tech&tech`.`Factura` (`idFactura`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero tienes que poner la consulta completa, por que el error dice que es sintaxis, y el error muestra una parte de la consulta.

Comment: Ese problema surge debido a la palabra `VISIBLE` que se puede apreciar en varias partes de tu código.  Desde MySQL 8+ puede haber índices visibles o invisibles, por lo que Workbench agrega por defecto la palabra `VISIBLE`. Si luego intentas ejecutar esos scripts en versiones de MySQL inferiores a la 8 tendrás el error de sintaxis, porque en esas versiones antiguas no existe la palabra `VISIBLE` ni `INVISIBLE`. La solución mejor es ejecutar todo en MySQL 8+ si es posible, y si no limpiar tus scripts borrando `VISIBLE` y/o `INVISIBLE` donde quiera que aparezcan.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, se me hace raro lo de la versión de MySQL ya que tengo la 8.0 CE, es algo que me advirtieron lo de tener mysql actualizado pero bueno, veré de sacar esas palabras reservadas a ver si funciona.

Comment: Ya logre solucionarlo, al final tuve que cambiar de versión en MySQL  al 5.7. Raro ya que se supone que en esa versión es donde aparecia VISIBLE/INVISIBLE automaticamente